# How to get file attributes of this file (paperclip) object in rails 4 using simple_form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, paperclip, simple-form

Im uploading a file into my rails 4 app using paperclip and simple_form with the following code.

What Id like to do in the following code is substitute the word "file" for the actual file name and extension in the dailogue box. Id also like to customize the message in the dialogue box. I wonder how to accomplish that.

views/uploads/_form.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for task.uploads.build, :html=> {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :task_id, :value => task.id %>

     <%= f.error_notification %>
     <%= f.file_field :sourcedata %>
     <%= f.button :submit, "Upload this file \nto server" ,:confirm => "Upload File",:class=> "upload_tasks_button"%>

 <% end %>
```

I appreciate any suggestions to customize the dialogue box.

Thanks

Comment: You want to substitute the word file for actual filename before upload?

Answer (score 0):

It costs a little bit, but take a look at http://fineuploader.com/.  It provide a really rich and powerful UI for file uploads.